# Given a set t of tuples containing elements from the set S, what is the most efficient way to build another set whose members are not contained in t?

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, pytorch

For example, suppose I had an `(n,2)` dimensional tensor `t` whose elements are all from the set `S` containing random integers. I want to build another tensor `d` with size `(m,2)` where individual elements in each tuple are from `S`, but the whole tuples do not occur in `t`.

E.g.

```
S = [0,1,2,3,7]
t = [[0,1],
     [7,3],
     [3,1]]

d = some_algorithm(S,t)

/* 
d =[[2,1],
    [3,2],
    [7,4]]
*/
```

What is the most efficient way to do this in python? Preferably with pytorch or numpy, but I can work around general solutions.

In my naive attempt, I just use

```
d = np.random.choice(S,(m,2))
non_dupes = [i not in t for i in d]
d = d[non_dupes]
```

But both t and S are incredibly large, and this takes an enormous amount of time (not to mention, rarely results in a `(m,2)` array). I feel like there has to be some fancy tensor thing I can do to achieve this, or maybe making a large hash map of the values in `t` so checking for membership in `t` is `O(1)`, but this produces the same issue just with memory. Is there a more efficient way?

An approximate solution is also okay.

Comment: For context, this is for a graph learning algorithm where `t` is the set of nodes that cooccur in random walks through the graph, and `d` is a random set of negative samples of nodes that do not occur together in random walks. `S` is the set of nodes that have had walks started from them.

Comment: `list(itertools.combinations(S,2)) `  generates all combinations of S of size 2.  How does that relate to your `d`?

Comment: @hpaulj ideally, `d` would be the set difference of all combinations of `S` of size 2 and `t`, however, because this set would be so large, any randomly generated subset of (s1, s2 | s1, s2 ∈ S)-t would be fine. What I'm asking is for an efficient way to filter out members of `t` from that set you propose

Comment: What is the expected size of `t` and `d`, compared to `|S|`? If `t + d << |S|^2`, just store `t` and `d` in a hash table and start generating elements randomly, and discard if it is in the set. Assuming  that for any random candidate `x`, then the probability:  `P(x exists in t or d) < C` (for some constant `C < 1`), the expected number of trials is `1/C`. So if for example, `t+d < 1/2|S|^2`, you are going to need (on average) no more than `2d` trials to draw `d` numbers on random.

Comment: If memory is an issue, you can instead `sort(t)` and use binary search. This will increase the time of each lookup to `O(logt)`, and add preprocessing of `O(tlogt)`, but no need to store large dataset

Comment: Corretion to above comment, number of trials is `1/(1-C)`, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my naive attempt would be a base-transformation function to reduce the problem to an integer set problem:

definitions and assumptions:

- let S be a set (unique elements)
- let L be the number of elements in S
- let t be a set of M-tuples with elements from S
- the original order of the elements in t is irrelevant
- let I(x) be the index function of the element x in S
- let x[n] be the n-th tuple-member of an element of t
- let f(x) be our base-transform function (and f^-1 its inverse)

since S is a set we can write each element in t as a M digit number to the base L using elements from S as digits.

for M=2 the transformation looks like
f(x) = I(x[1])*L^1 + I(x[0])*L^0

f^-1(x) is also rather trivial ... x mod L to get back the index of the least significant digit. floor(x/L) and repeat until all indices are extracted. lookup the values in S and construct the tuple.

since now you can represet t as an integer set (read hastable) calculating the inverse set d becomes rather trivial

loop from L^(M-1) to (L^(M+1)-1) and ask your hashtable if the element is in t or d

if the size of S is too big you can also just draw random numbers against the hashtable for a subset of the inverse of t

does this help you?

Comment: Ah yes. This is exactly what I was looking for. I was trying to figure out some way to map elements to prime numbers so tuples would be unique prime factorisations, and map to unique integers but this is far more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

If `|t| + |d| << |S|^2` then the probability of some random tuple to be chosen again (in a single iteration) is relatively small.

To be more exact, if `(|t|+|d|) / |S|^2 = C` for some constant `C<1`, then if you redraw an element until it is a "new" one, the expected number of redraws needed is `1/(1-C)`.

This means, that by doing this, and redrawing elements until this is a new element, you get `O((1/(1-C)) * |d|)` times to process a new element (on average), which is `O(|d|)` if `C` is indeed constant.

Checking is an element is already "seen" can be done in several ways:

- Keeping hash sets of `t` and `d`. This requires extra space, but each lookup is constant `O(1)` time. You could also use a [bloom filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) instead of storing the actual elements you already seen, this will make some errors, saying an element is already "seen" though it was not, but never the other way around - so you will still get all elements in `d` as unique.
- Inplace sorting `t`, and using binary search. This adds `O(|t|log|t|)` pre-processing, and `O(log|t|)` for each lookup, but requires no additional space (other then where you store `d`).

---

If in fact, `|d| + |t|` is very close to `|S|^2`, then an `O(|S|^2)` time solution could be to use [Fisher Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)  on the available choices, and choosing the first `|d|` elements that do not appear in `t`.